# Trying download an Atom package but getting an error

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying download scripts onto my atom editor. but I'm getting a strange error that I believe has something to do with node? This is one of the first packages I've tried to install so any help would be great. Here is the error.

[image: This seems stange]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some connection problem to github. You should try to clone that repositry directly with git. Most likely ssh-connections don't work from your location..